# Vivaldi does not export notes

Tags: vivaldi

I have created a few notes with Vivaldi 5.6, using the [Copy to note](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/panels/notes/#Copy_to_Note) command.

My notes are visible in the Web Panel:

[image]

I intend to export them as text files, so I used the Command Palette and chose [Export notes](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/panels/notes/#Exporting_Notes).

The command is executed as I have to choose a folder for the files but *no files are generated*.

What else should I set?

UPDATE: I have a special character in my user name, so maybe that's causing some irregularity. It would surprise me though, the developers are from Norway and Iceland, they have some special characters, too.

Comment: `no files are generated` ... how do you know this? ... maybe they are saved in an unexpected location

Comment: @jsotola Then what's the point of selecting a directory for it? It should work yet the saving does not happen so I assume it is not working.

Comment: It used to work for me (for a few days) and tonight stopped working.  It asks you to choose a folder but puts nothing there, and no error message.  Previously, when it did work, after the folder selection a dialog would open   each time whether I granted permission for vivaldi to read and write to the directory.  I fear that maybe I clicked the wrong answer in the dialog and now it doesn't work at all.  In any case, bad behavior.  Vivaldi 5.6.2867.50 (Stable channel) stable (64-bit) 
- on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I tried this just now on Vivaldi 5.6 on Windows 11 and exporting notes worked fine for me.
The naming of the text files is perhaps a bit odd with 3-4 first letters of the note text and a number as the title, but I now have a few text files among my other files. It might be best to first create a new folder and then select it as the export destination. Then the notes don't get lost among the other files.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to get around the fact that Export Notes is not working -- that's to go to the place where the Notes are stored on the file system, which to me is ~/.config/vivaldi/Default/Notes, open that file with vim or emacs to extract the relevant entry (they're stored in JSON but not encoded, so the file is easy to search), and move the text where I want it. (I still had to replace "\n" by  actual newlines.)

Comment: Your experience just confirms that the function is not working. That's very annoying that there is no proper explanation or any fix.